# Force download file after query php mvc

Tags: php, download

I got stuck with the code left by the first programmer of the current webpage that I'm on. He create his own custom framework.

My problem is that I have created a function for file export cause there is a feature wherein I should export the query to textfile so client/user download it automatically via forcing the browser to download the generated file: heres the code of my force download.

**Note:** I have already search with others forums as well as at Stackoverflow but I can't find an answer. This is my current code:

```
if(!defined('APPLICATION_RUNNING')){
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die('acces denied');
}

if(defined('ANNOUNCE')){
    echo "\n<!-- loaded: ".__FILE__." -->\n";
}

if(!class_exists('APP_Ajax')){

class APP_Ajax extends APP_Base_Ajax
{
    function textfiles()
    {
        global $apptemplate, $appform, $appdb;

        if(!$appform->form_valid($this->post['formid'])) // if not b\valid form
        {
            json_return_error(5);
        }
        else
        {
            if(!empty($this->post['form'])) //if the post of form is not empty
            {
                $e = array();                   
            }
            else
            {
                json_return_error(6);//alert if form is empty
            }

            if(empty($this->post['form']['rowid']))
            {
                json_return_error(252); // if rowid is empty then raise error
            }
            else
            {           
                $rets = $this->post['form']['rowid'];
                $ids = explode(',',$rets);

                foreach ($ids as $kids)
                {
                    $sql = pg_query("SELECT * from tbl_patient WHERE id='$kids'");
                    $info = pg_fetch_assoc($sql);
                    $text[]  = ucwords($info['firstname']." ".$info['mi']." ".$info['lastname']).",".$info['medicalrecordnumber'].",".$info['referraldate'];
                }

                $output = implode( "\r\n" , $text );
                $randfile = rand(12345689,999999999)."_".date('m-d-Y');

                $f = fopen("templates/default/exports/".$randfile.".txt", "w");
                fwrite($f, $output);
                fclose($f);

                $file_name = ABS_PATH.'templates/default/exports/'.$randfile.'.txt';

                header('Pragma: public');   // required
                header('Expires: 0');// no cache
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
                header('Cache-Control: private',false);
                header('Content-Type: text/plain');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));
                header('Connection: close');

                readfile($file_name);// push it out
           }
      }
}

}
```

The code above produce no error, the file where created on the path I create but
the problem is that "No save as" or something, the browser do not download a file. When I use httpfox to view the headers, etc, etc, the result of the query is displayed on httpfox content tab, so nothings wrong with the code except that I want the browser to show the Download file(Save as dialog) so the user can save it to there Hard drives..

**Note 2#:** When I create a download link like `Download`, when I click the download link, the page returns me to the main page and no downloads at all.

Please give me a script or advice on how to work on this stuff. Thank you in advance.
Tell me if I'm missing something here.

Oops forgot to tell you, the website I'm on it do not allow external access to file for security that's why I can't link the export file it to other page  for download. :)

Comment: Why do you use an `header('Connection: close');`? Maybe that's the reason for the download not appearing.

Comment: I have tried remove the header('Connection: close'); yet no changes happens. but I see the result using httpfox.

Comment: Uhm. I have figured it a way to allow force download. What I did is just I modify the .htaccess :)

Comment: Please post your exact solution as answer and mark it as correct answer. Thus anyone else will have a knowledge benefit from that solution.

Comment: The original .htaccess was this <code><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]</code>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php/ [L]
</IfModule>